# How to access Secugen Hamster Plus from client-side using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fingerprint

I have a Secugen Hamster Plus device for reading fingerprints. What I have to do is take a fingerprint and save it to the server. All of this needs to be done with HTML5 and Javascript.

So any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not that I am aware of if they have a ready API for JavaScript (Pure Java they have) You can always try to raise a request here: http://www.secugen.com/download/sdkrequest.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through their provided **SDK**, and from my research we are not able to access it via USB on the web as **secuGen** is a propriety device.

Answer (score 0):

Reading fingerprint from the scanner through HTML5/Javascript is not supported by Secugen SDK. But they are provided by the 3rd party vendors, few are [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com/blog/cloud-computing/secugen-m2sys-partner-cloudabis-biometrics/), [CamsUnit](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html), [Jmtech](https://jomutech.com/html5webbiometricfingermodule.php).

Answer (score 0):

Don' know about java script but you can easily do it using java.

h[ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028081/implementing-secugen-real-time-fingerprint-capture-in-java/59387288#59387288](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028081/implementing-secugen-real-time-fingerprint-capture-in-java/59387288#59387288)